# How can I have different HOST_ID() for different sessions in my Webservice?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, session

I have an Asp .Net Webservice. In its method I call HOST_ID() function of SQL Server to get unique ID of each session or connection but I get one ID for each session. How can I make it Unique for each http session?

Comment: I deleted that comment about `@@SPID` as not sure if that will be suitable or not. But it is the SQL Server numeric identifier for a connection/session.

Comment: What is it you wanted to do with host_id() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Books Online:

> Returns the workstation identification number. The workstation identification number is the process id (PID) of the application on the client computer that is connecting to SQL Server.

This is unlikely to be unique.